# Bootstrap grid alignment not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a set of three "cards" (but not using the bootstrap card class) that I need to align horizontally and center on the page. I am setting the outer div to a full width, and trying to give each of the three `.info-card` classes equal `.col-lg-4` width. This is still keeping the cards floated left(removing the left float from the `.flip-card` class aligns the cards vertically. How can I get the columns applied correctly here?

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="flip-cards col-lg-12">
    <div class="info-card col-lg-4">
      <div class="front">
          <h3>Header</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <p>Title</p>
        <h6>lorem ipsum</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="info-card col-lg-4">
      <div class="front">
          <h3>Header</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <p>Title</p>
        <h6>lorem ipsum</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="info-card col-lg-4">
      <div class="front">
          <h3>Header</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <p>Title</p>
        <h6>lorem ipsum</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
  background-color: #eee;
}
.flip-cards .info-card {
  float: left;
  margin: 2% 1% 0% 1%;
  padding: 5% 0% 5% 0%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 600px;
}
.flip-cards .info-card:hover .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
}
.flip-cards .info-card:hover .front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flip-cards .info-card .front, .flip-cards .info-card .back {
  transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.flip-cards .info-card .front {
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 170px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: .5;
}
.flip-cards .info-card .front h3 {
  text-decoration: underline;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #6633cc;
}
.flip-cards .info-card .back {
  background-color: #6633cc;
  width: 200px;
  height: 170px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.flip-cards .info-card .back p {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 7px 0px 0px 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.flip-cards .info-card .back h6 {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
  bottom: 0;
}
.flip-cards .info-card .back h6 a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

@media (max-width: 400) {
  .flip-cards {
    margin-left: -3%;
  }

  .card-outer-wrapper {
    height: 260px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    max-width: 100vw;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: relative;
  }

  .card-outer-wrapper .card-wrapper {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    width: 200%;
  }
}
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/sxLodk6r/

Answer (score 0):

Let's redo it again.

This time I'll list all code which need to be fixed, and at last I'll paste all final html and css code for your convenient.

1. Add grid below `<div class="row">` in bootstrap.

   ```
   <div class="container">
       <div class="row"> <!-- Add This -->
           <div class="flip-cards col-lg-12 ">
           ...
           </div>
       </div> <!-- Add This -->
   </div>
   ```
2. Don't add any class which contain padding and margin with grid class in the same level.

   ```
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="info-card "> <!-- Separate this class -->
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
   ```
3. It would be better to avoid percent value in margin/padding top/bottom and it is easier for you to define the position of `.back` later in list 7.

   ```
   .flip-cards .info-card {
       margin: 20px 10px 0 10px;
       padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
   }
   ```
4. If you want to align `.info-card` center, replace `float:left` with `display:inline-block` in `.info-card` and add `.text-center` with `.col-lg-4`

   ```
   .flip-cards .info-card {
       display: inline-block;
       float: left;  /* Remove This! */
   }

   <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
       <div class="info-card ">
       ...
       </div>
   </div>
   ```
5. Don't use `overflow:hidden` in `.front`, instead, remove the `margin-top` in `h3`.

   ```
   .flip-cards .info-card .front { {
       overflow: hidden;   /* Remove This */
   }

   .flip-cards .info-card .front h3 {
       margin-top: 0px;
   }
   </div>
   ```
6. Remove `positon:absolute` in `.front`.

   ```
   .flip-cards .info-card .front {
       position: absolute;  /* Remove This! */
   }
   ```
7. Add `position:absolute` and `top:10px` in `.back`.

   ```
   .flip-cards .info-card .back {
       background-color: #6633cc;
       width: 200px;
       height: 170px;
       position: absolute;
       top:10px;
       -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
   }
   ```

My Html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="flip-cards col-lg-12 ">
                <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
                    <div class="info-card ">
                        <div class="front">
                          <h3>Header</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                            <p>Title</p>
                            <h6>lorem ipsum</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
                    <div class="info-card ">
                        <div class="front">
                          <h3>Header</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                            <p>Title</p>
                            <h6>lorem ipsum</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
                    <div class="info-card ">
                        <div class="front">
                          <h3>Header</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                            <p>Title</p>
                            <h6>lorem ipsum</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My Css code

```
.container{
  background-color: #eee;
}
.flip-cards .info-card {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 10px 0 10px;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 600px; 
}
.flip-cards .info-card:hover .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
}
.flip-cards .info-card:hover .front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flip-cards .info-card .front, .flip-cards .info-card .back {
  transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.flip-cards .info-card .front {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  height: 170px;
  opacity: .5;
}
.flip-cards .info-card .front h3 {
  text-decoration: underline;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #6633cc;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.flip-cards .info-card .back {
  background-color: #6633cc;
  width: 200px;
  height: 170px;
  position: absolute;
  top:10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.flip-cards .info-card .back p {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 7px 0px 0px 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.flip-cards .info-card .back h6 {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
  bottom: 0;
}
.flip-cards .info-card .back h6 a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

@media (max-width: 400) {
  .flip-cards {
    margin-left: -3%;
  }
  .card-outer-wrapper {
    height: 260px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    max-width: 100vw;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: relative;
  }
  .card-outer-wrapper .card-wrapper {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    width: 200%;
  }
}
```

Comment: I realized I forgot to add the `<div class="row">`, but that doesn't account for the columns not aligning: https://jsfiddle.net/sxLodk6r/1/

Comment: I applied your recommendations, but the boxes are still being forced to the left. They also need to only have about 10px between them. https://jsfiddle.net/sxLodk6r/3/